# Pyautogui gives me a Key Error in Win7 64-Bit

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

i'm using PyautoGUI v0.9.52 with Python 3.7.7, and my "+" Key is always changed to "*" when i run the code below. I tried to put the character + in typewrite Method but it appears as * too.
Is this a bug in PyautoGUI? Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 2

pyautogui.hotkey("winleft", "r")
pyautogui.typewrite("calc", interval = 1)
pyautogui.press("enter")

pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "2")
pyautogui.press("1")
pyautogui.press("8")
pyautogui.press("+")
pyautogui.press("3")
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Comment: Did u do: pyautogui.write('18+3') instead?

Comment: It didn't work!!! It always puts * instead of +.